# Clickable buttons and changing div's content

Tags: javascript, button, click

I have two sections of divs: left one – menu list, right one – image gallery

Every button from the menu list has a different content inside. When you click one of the buttons, the content changes on the right side. When you click the same button one more time, the content changes and goes back to image gallery.

The problem is that when I click on one project, I cannot click on another. I need to click the same button to go back to image gallery and then I can click another one.

I hope it makes sense.

HTML

```
<div grid-col="12" class="work">
  <div grid-col="6" class="work-sub project-sub" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3 style="border-top: 0px;">Project Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list">
      <h3 style="border-top: 0px;">Year</h3>
    </div>

    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-graphics">Graphics</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list" style="border-top: 0px;">
      <h3>2020</h3>
    </div>

    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-chinese">Chinese</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list" style="border-top: 0px;">
      <h3>2020</h3>
    </div>

    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-experimental">Experimental</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list" style="border-top: 0px;">
      <h3>2020</h3>
    </div>

    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-feed">Feed</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list" style="border-top: 0px;">
      <h3>2019</h3>
    </div>

    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-rapidly">Rapidly</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list" style="border-top: 0px;">
      <h3>2018</h3>
    </div>

    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-closer">Closer</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list">
      <h3>2018</h3>
    </div>

    <div grid-col="8" class="work-list project-list" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-market">Market</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list" ;>
      <h3>2018</h3>
    </div>

    <div
      grid-col="8"
      class="work-list project-list"
      style="border-right: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"
    >
      <h3>
        <a href="#" id="btn-italia">Italia</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div grid-col="4" class="work-list project-list" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <h3>2017</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div grid-col="6" class="work-sub" style="border-right: none; border-top: none;">
    <div grid-col="4" class="project-photos project-sub">
      <div grid-col="6" class="project-photo easy-quick">
        <div id="1">
          <div class="button-container square">
            <span class="mas">Graphics</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="Graphics.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <span class="mas">Chinese</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="Chinese.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container vertical">
            <span class="mas">Experimental</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="Experimental.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container square">
            <span class="mas">Feed</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="Feed.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <span class="mas">Rapidly</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="Rapidly.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <span class="mas">Closer</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="Closer.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <span class="mas">Market</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="Market.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container vertical">
            <span class="mas">Italia</span>
            <button type="button" name="Hover">
              <img src="feed-italia.jpg" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="3" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="4" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="5" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="6" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="7" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="8" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="9" style="display:none;">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="click.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  padding: 4px 15px 4px 15px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 17px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:  #000;
}

a:hover {
  color: #666666;
}

.menu, .work {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu h2 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

[grid-col] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

[grid-col="12"] {
    width: 100%;
}

[grid-col="8"] {
    width: 66.66667%;
}

[grid-col="6"] {
    width: 50%;
}

[grid-col="4"] {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

[grid-col="2"] {
    width: 16.66667%;
}

#menu-info-sub {
  float: right;
}

.menu-info-sub {
    float: right;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
    display: none;
  transition: transform 0.8s linear;
}

.menu-info-sub h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.menu-info-sub h2:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

h2.text {
  text-transform: none;
}

.work {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.work h2 {
  border-top: 0px;
}

.work-list h3 {
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.work-photo h2 {
  border-top: none;
}

.work-sub {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.work-list {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.project-list h3 {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.project-list:first-child {
  border-top: 0px;
}

.project-list:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.work-photo {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.project-photos {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.project-photo {
  width: 100%;
}

html {
  overflow: scroll;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}

.project-photo img {
  width: 100%;
}

.project-sub {
  flex: 5;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#btn-graphics').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#2')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#2').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})

$('#btn-chinese').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#3')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#3').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})

$('#btn-experimental').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#4')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#4').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})

$('#btn-feed').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#5')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#5').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})

$('#btn-rapidly').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#6')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#6').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})

$('#btn-closer').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#7')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#7').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})

$('#btn-market').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#8')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#8').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})

$('#btn-italia').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#9')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  } else if ($('#9').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#1')
      .show()
      .siblings('div')
      .hide()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify your jquery a lot.

Give each of your buttons a class e.g. .button-toggle, instead of id's give them an attribute with the wanted number to open.

Then you listen for `$('.button-toggle').on('click', function() { ... )`
in the function you can get the number from in the attribute over "this" and then to further simplify stuff just toggle the class "d-none" on the hidden element (also obviously you should hide the divs using d-none in the first place).

jquery could look something like this

```
$('.button-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var firstToggle = $(this).data('toggle-one');
    var secondToggle = $(this).data('toggle-two');

    $('#'+firstToggle).toggleClass('d-none');
    $('#'+secondToggle).toggleClass('d-none');
})
```

Button could look something like this

```
<a class="button-toggle" data-toggle-two="3" data-toggle-one="4" href="#" id="btn-graphics">Graphics</a>
```

forgot to mention d-none is a standard bootstrap class, when youre not using bootstrap, just define it on your own

```
.d-none {
    display: none;
}
```

hope i could help

Comment: thanks! Can you please explain me why I need to use two toggle classes (toggle-one and toggle-two)?

Comment: Its not well optimised, but I thought for using one toggle to open the new div and one for closing the opened div.